# What is the difference between using set to make equation or not?

Tags: notation

What is the difference between $x = a, b, c$ and $x \in \{a, b, c\}$?
Which expression should I use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first one is not well written in the mathematics idiom, but will be understood to mean to most people versed in the idiom; the second one which is well written and could be understood by even a computer. I'd read $x = a, b, c$ as "$x$ is equal to either $a,b$ or $c$".